# Projection theorem for nonclosed subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Is there a substitute for the projection theorem for Hilbertspaces (if $M$ is a closed subspace of $H$ then $H = M \oplus M^\perp$) in the case that $M$ is a linear subspace of $H$ which is not closed?

Comment: What kind of a substitute are you looking for? In other words, what is it that you want to be able to do?

Comment: I want to get a similar decomposition of $H$. Maybe i can use $(M^\perp)^\perp)$ instead?

Comment: $(M^{\perp})^{\perp}=M^{c}$ is the closure of $M$. So, yes, $H=(M^{\perp})^{\perp}\oplus M^{\perp}$, but you don't gain much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orthogonal complements are always closed, so you find
$$
H = M^\perp \oplus M^{\perp\perp}.
$$
Moreover, it holds $M^{\perp\perp} = \overline M$, which is the closure of $M$. To see this, first one can prove $M^\perp = (\overline M)^\perp$. This implies
$$
M^{\perp\perp} =  (\overline M)^{\perp\perp} = \overline M,
$$
where the latter equality uses closedness of $\overline M$. Thus, we have the decomposition
$$
H = \overline M\oplus M^\perp.
$$